# Is it possible to use either less than 3 \rput or just a single \uput to rotate and translate the following object?

Tags: pstricks

Is it possible to use either less than 3 `\rput` or just a single `\uput` to rotate and translate the following object? Please don't use other transformation macros because my intent is to learn how `\rput` and `\uput` work.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\def\obj#1{\psline[linecolor=#1](2,6)(6,6)(7,3.5)(6,1)\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](8,6)
    \obj{red}
\end{pspicture}
\qquad
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](8,6)
    \obj{red}
    \rput(6,1){\rput{180}(0,0){\rput(-2,-6){\obj{blue}}}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\def\obj#1{\psline[linecolor=#1](2,6)(6,6)(7,3.5)(6,1)\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](8,6)
    \obj{red}
\end{pspicture}
\qquad
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](8,6)
    \obj{red}
    \rput{180}(8,7){\obj{blue}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Genius! I am waiting for another answer with `\uput` if possible. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\def\obj#1{\psline[linecolor=#1](2,-2.5)(3,0)(2,2.5)(-2,2.5)}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-4,-4)(4,4)
    \obj{red}
\end{pspicture}
\qquad
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-4,-4)(4,4)
    \obj{red}%
    \rput{180}{\obj{blue}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The only "bonus" here is the shift in origin via a different `pspicture`, which drops a coordinate addition to `\rput` (or it defaults to `(0,0)`). Hmmmm...

Comment: Practically `\obj` and `pspicture` should not be changed because it will affect the existing other objects.

Answer (score 0):

The following is taken from the PSTricks bible.

[image]

Thus there are infinite number of ways to invoke `\uput` to mimic `\rput{180}(8,7){\obj}` (the answer given by David Carlisle).

As an example, I choose

```
\uput{1}[60]{180}(!8 1 2 div sub 7 3 sqrt 2 div sub){\obj{blue}}
```

Honestly, I don't know when  we have to use `\uput` instead of `\rput` (in the case of handling zero dimensional objects). Is it just a personal preference?